# Transactions in Redis with read operations

Tags: transactions, redis, atomic

Using Redis, I want to perform an atomic sequence of commands, i.e. I need to guarantee that no other client will perform changes in the database while the sequence is being executed.

If I used **write** commands only, I could use `MULTI` and `EXEC` statements to assure atomicity using transactions. However, I would also like to use **read** commands in my transactions. Hence I cannot use `MULTI`, because read commands are also being queued!

Basically, in atomic manner, I need to do following:

1. Read `x` from the database,
2. Based on `x`, store `f(x)` to the database.

Both 1. and 2. should be part of a single, atomic transaction.

Is there a simple way how to do that?

Comment: You can try use Lua scripting: http://redis.io/commands/eval

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are two good solutions to your problem.

**Option 1:**

You need to issue a `WATCH` on the key you are reading from. Your transaction would look something like this:

```
WATCH x
x = GET x
MULTI
SET y, f(x)
EXEC
```

In this example, the write commands inside the multi block will be executed atomically, but **only** if the value of key `x` has not changed since `WATCH` was called. This is called an optimistic lock. If the value of `x` does change your application will get an error and will need to decide what to do next, which is likely to try again using the new value of `x`.

**Option 2:**

Redis now supports lua scripting, and lua scripts are executed atomically. If you can encapsulate your logic into a lua script, you can read your key, run your `f(x)` logic, and store the result, all atomically. This can be tricky or even a non-option depending on the logic you are performing. You might have to even do ugly hacks like pass values to lua by hardcoding them directly into the script you want redis to execute. That said, if you get it working this method should be reliable and performant, and you don't have to deal with handling `EXEC` failures.

Comment: Option 1 is perfect for my needs as iterative retrying of the operation seems as a reasonable solution. Currently, my application logic is much more complex in comparison to the example I have provided, yet I'll definitely have a look at Lua. Thanks a lot!

Comment: what if read operation is based on previous write operations's result, e.g., rpush return list  length, if length > some threshold, need to read from another key, then do some write operation again..  all these operation are inside a single transaction.